# Getting java errors trying to run leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to build a project that uses `leiningen` -- though my issue seems to be with leiningen and not with the project.

When I run `lein figwheel dev` (for a project that has a `/dev` folder configured correctly) I get the following:

```
Figwheel: Cutting some fruit, just a sec ...             
Unrecognized option: --add-modules                       
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.        
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Which indicates it's an error with the JVM, but I'm not familiar enough with working with any of `JVM` / `clojure` / `lein` to know what I should be doing to fix it.

Some (hopefully!) helpful information about my stack:

```
$ java --version                         
openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16                                               
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.1+13-Debian-2)                  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.1+13-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing)

$ lein --version           
Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 1.8.0_171 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone this repo and see if it solves your problems:    https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-template

Be sure to read the README.txt file and follow the instructions.

For this project, all you need is:

```
> lein figwheel
```

I'm not sure what you have in your `./dev` folder - that's probably the problem.

Comment: BAH! You're right, I believe I was looking at the wrong place for the misconfiguration. Thanks. It's requesting some `JVM` configuration that doesn't seem to be valid / was removed in JDK 9... ugh.